# Is it possible to sample the Dirac delta function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, sampling

The Dirac delta function can be a [probability measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#As_a_measure) with the [unit/Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_step_function) as its cumulative distribution function.

Is it possible to sample such a distribution? If a random variable $X$ has this distribution, would every observed value be $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the exact interpretation of it in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Why the restriction "in quantum mechanics"? This is the only meaning this mathematical notion can have.

Comment: @Did It wasn't intended to be a restriction, but rather and example of a field that does exactly what op was asking. However I can understand how it can be read that way.

In regards to other meanings of the Dirac delta function, I don't believe that every application of the delta function interprets it as a probability distribution.